# Is it possible to add a link inside the content property using css?

Tags: javascript, css, twilio, twilioflexwebchat

```
#twilio-customer-frame > div > div > div.Twilio-RootContainer-default.css-wct8tc > div > div.Twilio-MainContainer-default.css-18ljn0d > div.css-10po79b > div > div.Twilio-MessagingCanvas-default.css-18ljn0d::before{
  content: "I want this content to be a link and I can only use css";
}
```

I am using twilio webchat, it does not have a specific component to put the text where I want, so I have been forced to use css to place it on your site, the problem is that in that text I want to put a link through css but I can't get it, any suggestions?
Greetings

Comment: Nope, CSS content is plain text only.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to add content to the [`MessagingCanvas`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/webchat/configuration#messagingcanvas). Perhaps you could ask a new question that is around how to add content to that Component, including what you have tried, rather than this more specific one about CSS generated content?